# Union Find with F#

Tags: data-structures, f#

Regarding data structures available in F#
is there any "official" implementation of [disjoint set data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) like implementations of Union find ?

All I could find with Google is this snippets here:

[Weighted Quick-Union with Path Compression](http://www.fssnip.net/snippet/5D/5)

Please note that I'm a beginner in F# and in programming as well.
What would be the efficient alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented it myself
its not so difficult. I hope its bug-free

`UnionFind.fs`

```
// union find by rank with path compression

namespace UnionFind


// using array from 1..N 
// don't use .[0]

type Node = { Parent:int ; Rank:int}

type Partition (N:int) = 

    let nodearray =   [| for i in 0..N do yield {Parent = i; Rank = 0} |]

    let length = (Array.length nodearray) - 1

    member p.Item 
        with get(idx) = nodearray.[idx]

    member p.find (i) = 
        let mutable tmp0 = i
        let mutable tmp1 = p.[i].Parent
        while (tmp0 <> tmp1) do tmp0 <- tmp1
                                tmp1 <- p.[tmp1].Parent
        tmp0
    member p.find_compress (i) :int =
        let mutable tmp0 = i
        let mutable tmp1 = p.[i].Parent
        let rec one_step ok list =
            match ok with 
              | false -> list
              | true ->   tmp0 <- tmp1
                          tmp1 <- p.[tmp1].Parent
                          one_step (tmp0<>tmp1) (tmp0::list) 

        let list = one_step (tmp0<>tmp1) [i]  
        // ranks stay the same with find_compress
        list |> List.head |> (fun i ->  let r = nodearray.[i].Rank
                                        (nodearray.[i] <- {Parent = tmp0 ; Rank=r} ))
        list |> List.tail |> List.iter ( fun i -> let r = nodearray.[i].Rank
                                                  (nodearray.[i] <- {Parent = tmp0 ; Rank=r} ))

        tmp0

    member p.union_by_rank (i,j) : bool = // returns false if i and j hav the same parent, true otherwise
       if i=j then false else
          let x = p.find_compress(i)
          let y = p.find_compress(j)
          let rx = p.[x].Rank 
          let ry = p.[y].Rank

          if x=y then false else
             if (rx<ry) then nodearray.[x] <- {Parent = y; Rank = rx}                         
             if (ry<rx) then nodearray.[y] <- {Parent = x; Rank = ry}                
             if (rx=ry) then nodearray.[x] <- {Parent = y; Rank = ry}
                             nodearray.[y] <- {Parent = y; Rank = ry+1}
             true                             

    member p.print() = 
       printfn "%A" nodearray

    member p.output() = [|for i in 0..length do yield (i,p.find_compress(i))|]
```

Answer (score 3):

**F# Data Structures**

> Regarding data structures available in F#  is there any "official"
>   implementation of disjoint set data structures like implementations of
>   Union find ?

I don't know of any official version.

The most noted source of F# data structures:

- [F# Collection Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967652.aspx)
- [FSharpx.Collections](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections)

There use to be the F# [PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) which was one file that had lots of useful code, but it has now been broken down into parts.

Check out [Jack Fox's post](http://jackfoxy.com/f-data-structures/) for respected info on F# data structures.

For domain specific data structures search the [F# community projects](http://fsharp.org/community/projects/).

**Specifically for Union/Find:**

In [Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/index.html) in [lib.ml](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/OCaml/lib.ml)
John Harrison defines `equate` and `canonize`.

In the F# translation in [lib.fs](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning/lib.fs) they are still `equate` and `canonize`.

And from the [notes](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/wiki/Usage-Notes) during the translation:

See: [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)
See: [Topics in Automated Deduction - Lecture 5 - Page 4: Union/Find](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/G22.3033-007/lec/lec5.pdf)

`union` is called `equate`.
`find` is called `canonize`.

> What would be the efficient alternatives ?

I don't know if John Harrison's code is more efficient as I have not run any test. I also don't know of any other implementation, but I do know that version works and works well as the part of the core for a automated theorem prover.